# C# Return generic class from method

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my code below, with unimportant parts redacted:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    //...
}

public class Summary
{
    //...
}

public class Db : IDb
{
    public Response<Summary> Generate()
    {
        //...
        return new Response<Summary>
        {
            //...
        };
    }

    public Response<Summary> Execute<Summary>()
    {
        return Generate();
    }
}
```

I get an error that says:
    `Cannot implicitly convert type Response<Service.Models.Summary> to       Response<Summary>.`

Am I using generics wrong? Basically, I am expecting to see a Response model when I call the method Generate(), and in this instance T is the Summary class.

---

The interface I'm implementing is this:

```
public interface IDb
{
    Response<T> Execute<T>();
}
```

Comment: Why not post your code so people can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added code snippets, thanks

Comment: I don't see why this is getting close votes. It seems like a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `public Response<Summary> Execute<Summary>()` has a generic parameter of `Summary` that is overriding the class definition of `Summary`. The return type of `Response<Summary>` in `Execute<Summary>()` is a different type than the return in `Generate()`.

It seems likely that you code should be:

```
public Response<Summary> Generate()
{
    //...
    return new Response<Summary>
    {
        //...
    };
}

public Response<Summary> Execute()
{
    return Generate();
}
```

---

Given the addition of your interface `IDb` then the above answer doesn't work.

You must implement `Execute` as `public Response<T> Execute<T>()` and that means that the return type `Response<T>` is **not** the same as `Response<Summary>` at **compile-time**. So the error is correct.

You basically now have a design flaw.

It's likely that you need to make this change:

```
public class Db : IDb<Summary>
{
    public Response<Summary> Generate()
    {
        //...
        return new Response<Summary>
        {
            //...
        };
    }

    public Response<Summary> Execute()
    {
        return Generate();
    }
}

public interface IDb<T>
{
    Response<T> Execute();
}
```

Comment: A good reason why it's useful to follow the common practice of prefixing your generic types with `T` :)

Comment: thing is when I change `Response<T> Execute<T>()` to `Response<T>  Execute()` in the IDb interface, it says "namespace T cannot be found".

Comment: @Danny - You added the interface definition which explains why you had `public Response<Summary> Execute<Summary>()` - you should have implemented it as `public Response<T> Execute<T>()` and that would have made the problem more obvious to you. I've updated my answer with a suggestion. Just as a side note, please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Always append new information after answers are added.